# Twitter/Facebook OAuth hiding token in URL

Tags: php, http, url, get

When my users use Twitter or FB Connect I don't want the OAuth token show up in the callback URL like so:

`http://mysite.com/signup?state=5cf2199d5949568a264561f9b4b2d2b8&code=AQBQwuHD6F6ugE9vVUiB_4fHH4C3LGMUHYFyo51TQ9QrIHUavO9XxySUbUvunBECejf47gomxUS4gb6RdCFh4vS3BLy9UPY7kYSyZCN_DKytsymxIXISvznhj_GymeqzlTtBlIj7KZjipcjQjaxLJYyTL_3snBKxc2x72uc5WNvEk7WHbci4FkX03QGGGRlxJtw`

I would like to hide those variables so it can just be `http://mysite.com/signup` like, for instance, http://lockerz.com/ does with their OAuth process. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Sessions are a good way to go, although I don't know how much securer that would be.

Comment: How would would that work with sessions? Because the thing is the callback has the variables in it already? Maybe a landing page that redirects to the actual page? or JS? I'm not sure

Comment: You'd store the `state` in a session, then that way it's not visible to the user. I assume that's what you're trying to do?

Comment: No,that I understand, what I want to do is hiding in the URL, I don't want it to show up there, have a clean URL so to speak. If you check lockerz connect process you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the way I did this was having a landing page to work as my callback, meaning that I redirect to a page that is not the one the user started at before redirecting to the actual page.

In this page I set the variables I need so the next page can work properly and even be refreshed and not getting Twitter or FB Auth errors due to already expired tokens